# JavaScript form validation in C# form

Tags: javascript, c#

I need to use JavaScript for form validation to make fields required. The script I'm using to check fields for input requires the form name and field name. I tried modifying the `Html.BeginForm` to include the form name, but now submissions don't work and it displays "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm {" on the page.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id="frm", name = "frm"} )) {

 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)<br /><font style="color: red;">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)</font>
</div>

<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["frm"]["PNTR_MAX"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "" || x == "    ") {
            newcontent.innerHTML = "Error: PNTR Max is required";
            return false;
        }
    }
 </script>
```

**Update** Input now successfully submits and updates, however the form validation isn't working/doing anything.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Table9_1", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "validateForm", id="frm", name = "frm"} )) {

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)<br /><font style="color: red;">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PNTR_MAX)</font>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["frm"]["PNTR_MAX"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "" || x == "    ") {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Error: PNTR Max is required";
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just use `document.forms[0]["PNTR_MAX"]`?  Or the built-in required field validation in MVC?  Also, setting the action and controller name to null is probably why submissions don't work.

Comment: I think more simpler way is to validate through model

Comment: just use the `[Required]` attribute. What's the point of this

Comment: I can't use the model for validation, for reasons I'm not going to get into. I know this is less efficient but I have to use javascript.